# Python Classes: Map attributes to json keys

Tags: python, json, serialization

Just found this very neat way in `Go` to define the correlating `json key` for a class attribute, where the former is the class attribute definition and the latter what `key` it translates to in a `json`.

This approach allows to *auto-magically* serialize a class to a given json-structure (e.g. when you're dealing with many different REST APIs that expect different payloads) but also allows translating a `json` payload to a class instance.

Any way of achieving something similar with Python? I so far always tried to map my attribute names to the `json` structure, but it becomes an impractical mess when the API e.g. deals with `camelCase` or some abbreviations instead.

```golang
type EmailpkiSmime struct {
    Locked     string `json:"_locked"`
    ObjectType string `json:"_type"`
    Reference  string `json:"_ref"`
    Cert       string `json:"cert"`
    Comment    string `json:"comment"`
    Dn         string `json:"dn"`
    // Domaincert default value is false
    Domaincert  bool     `json:"domaincert"`
    Emails      []string `json:"emails"`
    Expires     string   `json:"expires"`
    Fingerprint string   `json:"fingerprint"`
    // Key default value is ""
    Key  string `json:"key"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    // Realname default value is ""
    Realname string `json:"realname"`
    // Trust default value is false
    Trust bool `json:"trust"`
}
```

Comment: Dataclasses in python might be the thing you are looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: marshmallow + marshmallow-dataclasses can do this for you, see the duplicate.

Comment: Use either a library like dataclass-wizard which supports [custom key mappings](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_use_cases/custom_key_mappings.html) and also adds auto type conversion, or also check out [a gist](https://gist.github.com/rnag/ddd678b42af0ed97193c8b763d216d58) I added which allows you to set up field aliases for a simple dataclass, and then just initialize it from a dictionary object, `**kwargs` style.